# How to parse a generic List inside classes with Moshi JSON codegen

Tags: android, json, kotlin, generics, moshi

I'm moving from Gson to Moshi with codegen and I'm lost about how to proceed with the following example.

I have this classes:

```
abstract class AbstractBaseModel {
    var id: Long = 0
    var deleted: Boolean = false
}

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class OneModel(val name: String) : AbstractBaseModel () 

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class OtherModel(val city: String) : AbstractBaseModel () 

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Another(val color: String) : AbstractBaseModel () 

// etc...
```

And I'm trying to use the Moshi adapter for this class:

```
data class Response<T>(val result: ResponseResult<T>?, val error: CustomError?, val id: Int) {
    data class ResponseResult<T>(val records: List<T>, val length: Int)
}
```

`T` can be `OneModel`, `OtherModel`, etc... always extending `AbstractBaseModel`

I tried with `val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<OdooResponse<T>> = moshi.adapter(Types.newParameterizedType(OdooResponse::class.java, Any::class.java))` but this only returns `records` as a list of `LinkedHashMap` instead any model so after I'm getting a `ClassCastException: com.squareup.moshi.LinkedHashTreeMap cannot be cast to AbstractBaseModel`

Is possible to parse this avoiding custom adapters? I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you find the solution?